# Docker compose failed in production server but not in pc

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I have developed an application in node js that needs to connect to MongoDB because of that I implemented a wait-for.sh script, when I run the entire application in my computer docker everything goes well, but when I run it in my digital ocean ubuntu 20.04 server it crashed with the following error

```
Node.js v17.4.0
/usr/app/wait-for.sh:3
# original script: https://github.com/eficode/wait-for/blob/master/wait-for
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

This is the dockerfile

```
FROM node:17-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --quiet
COPY . .

COPY wait-for.sh wait-for.sh
RUN chmod +x wait-for.sh

# Deleting windows characteres
RUN apt-get install -y dos2unix # Installs dos2unix Linux
RUN find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \; # recursively removes windows related stuff
```

The docker compose

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  monitor:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app/
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - app-network
    command: ./wait-for.sh db:27017 -- node index.js
  
  db:
    image: mongo
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
  node_modules:
```

And the wait for link
[wait for script](https://github.com/eficode/wait-for/blob/master/wait-for)

I don't know why is this happening

Comment: have you tried running the script from inside the container interactively to check if the dos2unix fix worked?

Comment: The dos2unix command in the Dockerfile does nothing, since the `volumes:` hide everything that's in `/usr/app`.  I'd suggest removing this `volumes:` block to use the code built (and corrected) in the image.